# Why is cpu power management not working in Server 2012 with Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012

We've been using Server2008R2 with Hyper-V for a couple of years now and chose it at the time because of its ability to make use of Intel SpeedStep and AMD PowerNow!
Now with Server 2012 and Hyper-V V3, all power management abilities seem to be gone. The CPUs are always at full speed and our servers need twice the energy as before while idling. (Yes, the CPU P-states are enabled in the BIOS)
Is this by design? Is there a workaround to enable cpu power management again? Despite the great new features of Hyper-V 3, this would be a show-stopper for us since we are very concerned about energy consumption.

Comment: so if you open an elevated powershell prompt and run the following "gwmi -comp pies085 -NS root\cimv2\power -Class win32_PowerPlan | select ElementName, IsActive | ft -a" what do you see.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot execute gwmi on the server. I receive a RPC server exception 0x800706BA. 

Tried to disable the firewall and checked the RPC service with no change.
Powershell run with Admin privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at you power plan settings?  I believe if you have it set to High Performance, the CPUs are never parked and therefore always consuming maximum power.  Perhaps you can switch to Balanced or a Custom level that allows for power savings features to be enabled.

Harold